# Single- vs. multiple-card graphics solutions for a many-monitor setup?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, eyefinity

**For a six-monitor setup, is it better single-card solution (e.g. [this VisionTek Radeon HD 7870](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814129262)) or a two-card solution (e.g. 2x[Radeon R9 280](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127759))?**

Simplifications:

1. All six monitors function independently (as opposed to being parts of a larger display).
2. No video gaming or 3D AutoCAD-type applications.
3. There are plenty of PCIe slots.
4. Power supply capacity is adequate for any solution.
5. OS is Windows 8.
6. No brand preference.
7. Money matters, but only as a tie-breaker.

My main point of confusion is that there are six-monitor cards, but their selection is limited and they're often based on older GPU's.  I'm not sure if I should just go with one or get two newer GPU's.

It seems weird that many single-monitor solutions employ graphics cards with up to 4GB of video RAM, but most single-card solutions for six monitors have no more than 1GB of video RAM.  A multi-card solution would provide more video RAM; would this help avoid performance issues?

Note: Previously asked in [How to design a six-monitor setup?](https://superuser.com/questions/758703/how-to-design-a-six-monitor-setup), which was closed as being too broad.  Trying to keep this one focused, but please let me know if I can improve my question in any way.

Comment: Are you driving all six displays with a single application? Two GPUs could be better if you have two or more separate applications running. The driver can give each application its own GPU affinity (e.g. monitors 1-3 can be driven by GPU0 and 4-6 by GPU1), it would be a little bit different if you were discussing one application stretching its output across all 6 displays. That said, if I am not mistaken a 7870 and a R9 280 serve the same market segment - 2x of either one would generally perform better than 1x of the other.

Comment: @ Andon M. Coleman: Most applications are MS Office, web browsers, Visual Studio, and a few CAD's (not graphics-intensive ones).  I'm not sure if having, say, six different Excel sheets on six different screens counts as an application using all six displays.  I frequently move applications around one monitor to another.